# ID pela variável ele retorna nulo e se colocar o ID "na mão" ele retorna o objeto certo

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Estou tentando recuperar um código recebido por uma request para recuperar objetos do banco de dados, mas estou encontrando alguns problemas.

Realizando testes,substitui o id vindo do request, por um valor forçado ("escrito na mão") e consegui obter o objeto.

Segue meu código:

```
List<String> codigos = new ArrayList<>();


String idPeca = request.getParameter("idPeca");
ControlePeca cp = new ControlePeca();
for (Peca p1 : cp.buscarPecas(Peca.class)) {
    codigos.add(p1.getIdPeca());
}

for (String id : codigos) {
    System.out.println(id); //sai o id que, é o mesmo contigo em idPeca
    System.out.println(cp.buscarPorId(id)); //traz o objeto que tem o id
    System.out.println(cp.buscarPorId(idPeca)); //traz null
}


    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    Peca peca = (Peca) query.uniqueResult();
    session.clear();
    session.close();
    return peca;
}
```

Eu tenho uma classe PecaDAO que é chamada pelo controlador ControlePeca()

Este é o método que testei forçando os dados. Se eu substituir o id por uma string que tenha no banco ele retorna correto, mas pela variável não.

```
public Peca buscarPorId(String id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String hql = "from peca p where p.id = '" + **id** + "' "; 
}
```

Gostaria de saber o porque dessa busca retornar null apenas por vir do request.getParameter obs: já verifiquei se o valor vindo do request tem no banco, e sim tem;

Comment: Cara a primeira coisa a fazer é ver se o valor do Request está vindo corretamente. Já que quando você seta esse valor manualmente o método consegue efetuar a busca provavelmente esse valor vindo do request está nulo ou errado. Tente usar request.getParameter("idPeca").trim(); As vezes o parâmetro está vindo com espaço e por isso o método não está conseguindo encontrar.

Comment: Já resolvi, obrigado, desculpa a demora :)